# How do I take a screenshot of the dash, hud, and the application menu?

Tags: unity-dash, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the the dash, HUD and application menu (separately). But I am having difficulty getting a screenshot: the dash or HUD disappears before I can take it. I would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch the *Screenshot* application and check the '*Grab the whole screen* option. More importantly, set a non-zero value (say 5 seconds) for the '*Grab after a delay of* ...' option.

[image]

Then press the '*Take Screenshot*' button and make sure the dash/HUD etc. is enabled when the screenshot is set to be captured (current time + set delay).

Answer (score -1):

You can do a screenshot with just your keyboard. Use your mouse to keep the dash / HUD not hidden while you're using one of these combinaison of keys :

- <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for all the desktop
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for the active window (in my case, Firefox window) -> *this combinaison isn't what you're looking for, but you would probably find it useful in other cases*
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> for an area you select

The last option can be done with the screenshot software of Ubuntu named *screencast*

Comment: Yeah, but this won't probably solve the actual problem: "**dash or  HUD disappearing** before I can take it." Those elements will probably close as soon as you press the keys.